# changing rootviewcontroller causing memory leak

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I checked all questions in SO before asking my own, but none of them works for me.

When I open my app at the first run, I call FirstViewController (it contains two buttons: Sign Up or Login). If the user choose to sign up, I bring RegisterViewController (it contains a button that took the user to login in case he change his mind). Finally a LoginViewController (also contains a button that open the sign up screen)

The code of the two buttons in FirstViewController

```
- (IBAction)signupPressed:(id)sender {
    AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    app.window.rootViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RegisterViewController"];
}

- (IBAction)loginPressed:(id)sender {
    AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    app.window.rootViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
}
```

the code of the RegisterViewController button that leads to the LoginViewController (I have tried one of the solutions but it fails)

```
- (IBAction)loginPressed:(id)sender {
    AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;


    UIViewController *previousRootViewController = app.window.rootViewController;

    app.window.rootViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];

    // Nasty hack to fix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763020/leaking-views-when-changing-rootviewcontroller-inside-transitionwithview
    // The presenting view controllers view doesn't get removed from the window as its currently transistioning and presenting a view controller
    for (UIView *subview in app.window.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UITransitionView")]) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
    // Allow the view controller to be deallocated
    [previousRootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
        // Remove the root view in case its still showing
        [previousRootViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    }];
}
```

LoginViewController: code that point back to the RegisterViewController.

```
- (IBAction)signupPressed:(id)sender {
    AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    app.window.rootViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RegisterViewController"];
}
```

The code presented above always create a new instance, I have tracked the app using Instruments.

Clicking on Signup on FirstViewController create the first instance of RegisterViewController

[image: when clicked on the sign up button on first screen]

Clicking on login button(RegisterViewController), then clicking on Signup button(LoginViewController)
[image: when clicking sign up button on login screen]

Both of these instances are issued by UIKit

[image: detail in instruments]

Is there any chance to manage these leaks?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Leaking views when changing rootViewController inside transitionWithView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763020/leaking-views-when-changing-rootviewcontroller-inside-transitionwithview)