# Changing rootViewController for Nav causes UISplitViewController to show detail on Compact portrait orientation

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm running into an issue where after changing the `rootViewController` on my `UINavigationController` and changing it back to my original `UINavigationController`, a `UISplitViewController` begins to show both it's master and detail view in a phone device on compact/portrait orientation (so not only on plus size phones, but also others).

Basic overview of architecture:
A `TabBarController` houses several tabs.  One of these tabs is a `UISplitViewController`.  I currently override the following to ensure that the `MasterViewController` is shown on compact orientations:

```
func splitViewController(_ splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondary secondaryViewController: UIViewController, onto primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

    // this prevents phone from going straight to detail on showing the split view controller
    return true
}
```

This works fine and displays the master on portrait as expected.  At any point pressing a button on another tab can create a new `UINavigationController` instance and display it, in which I'm doing the below to change the `rootViewController` to the newly created `UINavigationController` to display:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate
appDelegate?.window??.rootViewController = newNavVC
```

On dismiss, I'm just swapping the `UINavigationController` back to the original one through the same code above.  However, once I do this one time (create nav/display/dismiss), and I switch my tab back to the one with the `UISplitViewController`, it changes itself to show a side-by-side master detail view.  I didn't know this was possible in portrait mode for compact sizing.  I tried changing to any of the 4 preferred display modes in the `UISplitViewController`, but that didn't fix it.

Below is what it looks like (iPhone 6 simulator), am I missing delegates or misunderstanding  collapsing?

**Before**:

[image]

**After**:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the the logic that assigned the rootViewController with the code snippet found at this link:

[Leaking views when changing rootViewController inside transitionWithView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763020/leaking-views-when-changing-rootviewcontroller-inside-transitionwithview)

Basically you just create an extension for the UIWindow class that will set the root view controller correctly.

```
extension UIWindow {

/// Fix for https://stackoverflow.com/a/27153956/849645
func set(rootViewController newRootViewController: UIViewController, withTransition transition: CATransition? = nil) {

    let previousViewController = rootViewController

    if let transition = transition {
        // Add the transition
        layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    }

    rootViewController = newRootViewController

    // Update status bar appearance using the new view controllers appearance - animate if needed
    if UIView.areAnimationsEnabled {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: CATransaction.animationDuration()) {
            newRootViewController.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        }
    } else {
        newRootViewController.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }

    /// The presenting view controllers view doesn't get removed from the window as its currently transistioning and presenting a view controller
    if let transitionViewClass = NSClassFromString("UITransitionView") {
        for subview in subviews where subview.isKind(of: transitionViewClass) {
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
    if let previousViewController = previousViewController {
        // Allow the view controller to be deallocated
        previousViewController.dismiss(animated: false) {
            // Remove the root view in case its still showing
            previousViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to let us know who you are or why you're posting.

Please quote the relevant bits from the link for easier reading here.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  Answer modified.