# Changing the root view controller is not deallocating the previous view controllers on the same window

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My app launches with an initial view controller (lets call it as **StartVC**). Now when user presses a continue button, I am presenting a navigation stack (lets call it as **RegisterVC**) on top of **StartVC**. This navigation stack will contain 5 view controllers which I am pushing on it whenever user moves forward with button actions. After the 5th view controller, I am starting a new navigation stack (lets call it as **LoginVC**).

Now my use case is  *I dont want the **StartVC** & **RegisterVC** to reside in the memory as they are of no use once user has completed his registration. In order to achieve this, I am changing the AppDelegate window's root view controller to **LoginVC***

Below are the options which I tried on the 5th view controller of **RegisterVC**:

1) Changing the keywindow

```
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = LoginVC
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

2) Changing the window

```
   let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
   appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = LoginVC
   appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

3) Making the previous root view controller as nil before assigning a new one.

```
   let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
   appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = nil
   appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = LoginVC
   appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

4) I also tried the above options directly from the AppDelegate instead of doing it from the 5th view controller.

With all the above options, I tried debugging by looking at **deinit** on all view controllers, but none of them got deallocated. Also, I can see that 5th view controller under **LoginVC** in the xcode Debug View Hierarchy.

Because of not removing them from memory, the actual problem which I am facing is after presenting the **LoginVC**, I have a view controller whose background color alpha is less. Because of this I am seeing the **RegisterVC** 5th view controller underneath it.

Any help on this appreciated...

Comment: I'd suggest using ["debug memory graph"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992338/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-when-leaks-instrument-does-not-show-them/30993476#30993476) feature to see what is keeping strong reference to those old views controllers.

Comment: You should that answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27153956/849645. If your problem is the same as mine, this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the rootViewController setting is not the problem. Perhaps you have a retain cycle in your other view controllers that stops them from being deallocated.

There are many ways you could accidentally do this (capturing strong references to self in blocks, not marking delegates or other back references as weak, etc).

You might be able to figure it out with Instruments. Here's a tutorial: http://samwize.com/2016/05/30/finding-retain-cycle-with-instruments/

Comment: Or use Rob's suggestion of debug memory graph (see comment on your question)

Comment: Yeah it looks like you guys are right, it seems like there is a retain cycle but I am unable to figure out where its happening... I followed the 'debug memory graph' and 'instruments' but ended no where...I am cautiously managing the 'weak self' inside closures and 'weak delegate references' but its still hiding somewhere...I will post an update once I find out where its happening...Thank you for your quick responses..

Comment: Hi @Venkat Any update on this? I am facing the similar issue due to which previous controller is still visible while switching the controllers.

Comment: No @PriyankaMistry, Its still visible and I am unable to resolve this...The only way I found this getting resolved is by dismissing it while changing the root controller.

Comment: Hi @Naveen. Did you finally found the reason of the retain cycle? I’m facing a very similar issue and debug didn’t help me to find te root of the problem.

Comment: No @WedgeSparda, I didn't find the reason. So I resolved by dismissing it while changing the root controller (I think I used some animation so that user doesn't see it happening, not sure on this as its been long time).

Comment: @Naveen can you paste an example of what you did, please? I think you just placed a dismiss just before the animation, or maybe on its completion block.

Comment: @Naveen Ah, don't worry, I finally made ir work thanks to your suggestion. Thank you so much.