# Is memory exist for view controllers, if I change the rootViewController after five screens presented?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have an app that contains 7 screens. First screen is Login screen. After successful login, I change the root view controller to Home Screen in AppDelegate.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
HomeViewController *objHomeScreen  = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewControllerSID"];    [self.window setRootViewController:objHomeScreen];
```

Now Home screen will be presented. Next, after 3 controllers again I change rootViewController. Now my question is, will the 3 controllers exist in memory after changing the rootViewController?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically yes, the memory management will dispose those controllers, although you can ran into some issues as it is explained in this other thread of questions [Changing the root view controller is not deallocating the previous view controllers on the same window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45129995/changing-the-root-view-controller-is-not-deallocating-the-previous-view-controll) you can read the questions and answers here to have a better understanding of the memory management